# Content root Two modules in a project cannot share the same content root. IntelliJ adding module to Java project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

when trying to add a module to my java project in IntelliJ (by going to project structure, modules, + sign, jars or directories, i get the error "cannot save settings: content root "..." is defined for modules ".." & ".." (neither of them is the module I'm trying to add) Two modules in a project cannot share the same content root. Is there another way I can add the module to the project? Or someway to remove this error?

[java folder outside of source root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdT2h.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can not have one directory included into more than one IntelliJ IDEA module. When you add a new module, it's [content root](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html) directory must not point to directory which is already present in another module in the same project.